# XSLT with overlapping elements?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

So the title of this post may be a little misleading, but it's the best I can come up with.  I'm working on a project that uses TEI for encoding texts.  One of the requirements of my current work is to write XSL transformations to render the XML-encoded texts as HTML.  For the most part, no problem.  I'm kind of stuck on this issue, though:

```
    <l>There is <delSpan spanTo="A1"/>deleted text spanning</l>
    <l>multiple lines here.<anchor xml:id="A1"/> More text...</l>
```

Or, in other instances:

```
    <delSpan spanTo="A2"/>
    <l>Several deleted lines -- the delspan marker can appear </l>
    <l>outside of an l element.... </l>
    <anchor xml:id="A2"/>
```

(In case you're not familiar with TEI: l = a line of text; delSpan = span of deleted text that includes more than 1 line, page, or smaller unit.)

The goal is to display the text between the delSpan (A1) and its corresponding anchor (A1) -- "deleted text spanning / multiple lines here" -- with some formatting that indicates the deletion (e.g., text-decoration="line-through").  Right now, there's a template for "l" elements that handles most text formatting--or at least calls other templates to do it.

But these singleton tags are an anomaly; all other formatting/markup is accomplished with tags that actually contain the text they're meant to format.  Am I right in assuming that I need to process the delSpan and anchor elements in the "l" template?  What's the most elegant way to approach this problem and handle the pseudo-overlapping elements?

Sorry if this is a noob question or if I haven't given enough information.  I'm primarily a C/C++ programmer with little XSLT experience, so I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="delSpan|anchor"/>
    <xsl:template match="text()[preceding::delSpan[1]/@spanTo=following::anchor[1]/@xml:id]">
        <span style="text-decoration:line-through;">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<doc>
    <l>There is <span style="text-decoration:line-through;">deleted text spanning</span></l>
    <l><span style="text-decoration:line-through;">multiple lines here.</span> More text...</l>
</doc>
```

**Note**: The use of preceding and following axis and their meaning in document order. We don't overrides any previus template matching `l` elements. `delSpan` and `anchor` could also not been striped.

Comment: Thanks!  This is simple and elegant, and makes perfect sense to me now.  I'm enjoying the crash course in XSLT.

Comment: @Andrew Forrester: You are wellcome! Ask any time.

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue here is that the `delSpan` elements are not parents and that its ending and closing "element" are an empty element (`anchor` for closing). The link between opening and closing is done by referencing an `xml:id` tag.

There're multiple solutions to this issue, here's one from the top of my head, assuming you use XSLT 1.0 (it's much easier with XSLT 2.0). The idea is simple: find all siblings and apply them, but only if they are themselves followed by a sibling `anchor` with the correct `xml:id`:

```
<xsl:template match="delSpan">
   <xsl:variable select="@spanTo" name="spanTo" />
   <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[following-sibling::anchor[@xml:id = $spanTo]" mode="deleted" />
</xsl:template>

<!--
     do this for all elements you need to treat inside delSpan
     if they have children, remember to use apply-templates with mode deleted
 -->
<xsl:template match="l" mode="deleted">
   <strike><xsl:value-of select="." /></strike>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm not 100% sure this is entirely correct. It may go wrong if `<delSpan>` can be nested. If you're lucky, Dimitri Novatchev walks by and has a look, too.