# XSLT: Dealing with TEI milestone elements

Tags: xml, xslt, tei

My question is related to: [XSLT with overlapping elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495447/xslt-with-overlapping-elements) – but the proposed solution is not working for me.

**Input**

I have some TEI-XML encoded like this:

```
<delSpan spanTo="#abcbb6b8-b7bd-4b96-93c1-0a34500e12c0"/>
<lg>
    <l>some text that is deleted</l>
</lg>
<lg>
    <l>much more text</l>
    <l>another line of text</l>
</lg>
<anchor xml:id="abcbb6b8-b7bd-4b96-93c1-0a34500e12c0"/>
```

I want to process it with XSL and my output should look like:

```
<div class="delSpan">
    <div class="lg">
        <span>some text that is deleted</span>
    </div>
    <div class="lg">
        <span>much more text</span>
        <span>another line of text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**XSLT**
At the moment I am trying to work with the following templates:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:delSpan">
    <xsl:variable name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@spanTo, '#')"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-ending-with="tei:anchor[@xml:id=$id]">
        <div class="delSpan">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </div>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tei:lg">
    <div class="lg">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tei:l">
    <span>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

But this just produces the following output:

```
<div class="lg">
        <span>some text that is deleted</span>
    </div>
    <div class="lg">
        <span>much more text</span>
        <span>another line of text</span>
    </div>
```

So I am asking myself if there is any common and easy solution to deal with so called milestone-elements and process like described above?

Comment: It seems your code in a template matching `tei:delSpan` with `xsl:for-each-group select="*" ` tries to process any child elements of the `delSpan`, only it is an empty element in your sample so it doesn't have any children. I don't know the exact structure but usually matching on the parent element of the `delSpan` and then using `for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="tei:delSpan"` with a nested `group-ending-with` to grab the referenced `tei:anchor` seems like an easier approach. Or can the `delSpan` and `anchor` elements at different levels?

Comment: I am not sure, if I'm getting it right. Do you mean it this way?


    <xsl:template match="tei:div[@type='main']">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="tei:delSpan">
          <xsl:variable name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@spanTo, '#')"/>
         </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-ending-with="tei:anchor[@xml:id=$id]">
            <div class="delSpan">
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </div></xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:template>

Comment: And yes most of the time `delSpan`and `anchor` are on the same level (child elements of an `div`). The solutions of the preceding comment produces empty content.

Comment: It is hard exchanging code in comments, I have posted some attempt of an answer to have a formatted example, if you want to add any attempt and their failed results then please edit your question where you can present them in a formatted and readable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move the `for-each-group` to the parent element of any `delSpan` (or any element you expect to apply the wrapping to) then it would look like

```
  <xsl:template match="*[delSpan]">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="delSpan">
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="self::delSpan">
                  <xsl:variable name="id-ref" select="substring(@spanTo, 2)"/>
                  <div class="{local-name()}">
                      <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-ending-with="id($id-ref)">
                          <xsl:choose>
                              <xsl:when test="current-group()[last()] is id($id-ref)">
                                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[not(position() = last())]"/>
                              </xsl:when>
                              <xsl:otherwise>
                                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                              </xsl:otherwise>
                          </xsl:choose>
                      </xsl:for-each-group>
                  </div>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPJ9hEk/1